# How does cite bite achieve it's cache?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, caching

Can anyone shed light on how citebite achieves it's cache and in particular how it is able to display the cache having the same layout as the original page?

I am looking to achieving something very similar: I pulled the html from the source using

```
public static string sourceCache (string URL)
{
        string sourceURL = URL;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sourceURL);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;

            if (response.CharacterSet == null)
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            }
            else
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
            }

            string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();

            return data;
        }

        return "couldn't retrieve cache";
    }
}
```

which I then send to my database storing as `nvarchar(max)`. When loading the page to display the cache, I pull the field and set it as the innerhtml of a div property.

However, whereas on citebite their cache retains the styling and layout of the sourcepage, mine does not.

Where am I going wrong?

I have an asp.net 4.5 c# web forms website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one for this page, look at the source.  The secret is

```
<base href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432505/how-does-cite-bite-acheive-its-cache" />
```

> The HTML Base Element () specifies the base URL to use for all
>   relative URLs contained within a document.There is maximum one 
>   element in a document.

Comment: thank you. actually, my site works for this page, i guess because it contains that base element. i looked at the source of a page that doesn't work for my site, but does work in citebite and that doesn't have a base element, so are you saying that i have to look for that base element, and if it's not there insert one into my "cache" with the href set to to source url that i am caching?

Answer (score 0):

As per @Alex K above the base element appears to be the issue.

I have amended the code to check if the existing html has "base href" in it, and if not to insert the base element with the href set to the source url

```
public static string sourceCache (string URL)
    {
        string sourceURL = URL;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sourceURL);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;

            if (response.CharacterSet == null)
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            }
            else
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
            }

            string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();

            if (data.Contains("base href"))
            {
                return data;
            }
            else
            {
                //we need to insert the base href with the source url
                data = basecache(data, URL);
                return data;
            }                
        }

        return "couldn't retrieve cache";
    }

    public static string basecache (string htmlsource, string urlsource)
    {
        //make sure there is a head tag
        if (htmlsource.IndexOf("<head>") != -1)
        {
            int headtag = htmlsource.IndexOf("<head>");
            string newhtml = htmlsource.Insert(headtag + "<head>".Length, "<base href='" + urlsource + "'/>");
            return newhtml;
        }
        else if(htmlsource.IndexOf("&lt;head&gt;") != -1)
        {
            int headtag = htmlsource.IndexOf("&lt;head&gt;");
            string newhtml = htmlsource.Insert(headtag + "&lt;head&gt;".Length, "<base href='" + urlsource + "'/>");
            return newhtml;
        }
        else
        {
            return htmlsource;
        }
    }
```

So far i've only tested it on a few sites/domains but it appears to work, thank you so much Alex for your help.